# Paginate while returning array Api resource object

Tags: laravel, api, pagination, eloquent

I need to send multiple object to the api resources. So I am returning multiple Object inside array.Everything works fine but not showing any pagination meta data. like Current_page,next_page url etc.

```
return [                  
            'across_city' => ServiceProviderCollection::collection($across_city),
            'near_by' => ServiceProviderCollection::collection($near_by)
          ];
```

**My resource**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

    class ServiceProviderCollection extends  Resource
    {

        public function toArray($request)
        { 

            return
            [  

                'name'=>$this->forename,
                'rating'=>$this->rating,
                'price'=>$this->price,
                'distance'=>round($this->distances,1),

            ];
        }
    }
```

**My Controller:** 
here I have two type of users . near_by users and Users across the city. I sent them to the ServiceProviderCollection As an array.

```
$user_city = $userObj->location->city;
$locationObj = Location::whereNotIn('id', $blockeduser)->where('city',$user_city)->first();
$across_city = $locationObj->users()->simplePaginate(20);

    $near_by =  User::join('locations as l', 'users.location_id', '=', 'l.id')
        ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) as distances'))
        ->having('distances', '<', $max_distance)
        ->orderBy('distances', 'ASC')
        ->where('role_id',2)
        ->whereNotIn('id', $blockeduser)
        ->simplePaginate(20);

    return [
                'across_city' => ServiceProviderCollection::collection($across_city),
                'near_by' => ServiceProviderCollection::collection($near_by)
           ];
```

I want Json Data with pagination.

```
{"data":{
    "across_city": [
        {
            "name": "??",
            "rating": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "distance": 0,

        }
    ],
 "links": {
        "first": "",
        "last": "",
        "prev": null,
        "next": ""
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "path": "",
        "per_page": 2,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 6
    },
{
    "near_by": [
        {
            "name": "??",
            "rating": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "distance": 0,

        }
    ],
 "links": {
        "first": "",
        "last": "",
        "prev": null,
        "next": ""
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "path": "",
        "per_page": 2,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 6
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Should every collection get the pagnation-related data?

Comment: yes..every collection get pagination related data.

Comment: See answer. This should do it.  
Remember to accept the answer if it solvers your problem.

Comment: Whats the purpose of `ServiceProviderCollection ` and what is in `$across_city` / `$near_by `?

Comment: OK thanks for the details, Now its more clear. Do you get the pagination data with this: `return new ServiceProviderCollection(User::paginate());`?

Comment: ServiceProviderCollection::collection($across_city) working fine..but when i am trying to return multiple object to ServiceProviderCollection not showing any data related to pagination but paginate is working..I guess problem is in Data wrapping

Comment: You're right. The meta data is only getting added, if the resource collection is in the root of the response. If you are not required to maintain the structure, you could return directly the collections. Like so `return ['across_city' => $across_city, 'near_by' => $near_by ];` You'll get the needed information but completely different structured.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea, what the purpose of `ServiceProviderCollection` is. If it creates a regular collection then there is a [better way to do so](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections).

To be able to paginate a simple collection you need to add this helper function to your base:

```
function paginateCollection($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection ? $items : \Illuminate\Support\Collection::make($items);
    return new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

With this function in place you can make

```
return [                  
    'across_city' => paginateCollection(collect($across_city), 20),
    'near_by' => paginateCollection(collect($near_by), 20)
];
```

---

#### Edit

Do you have generated the corresponding resource collections?
Like so: `php artisan make:resource Cities --collection`

If so, you can return a [paginated resource collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#pagination)

Comment: Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::paginate does not exist."

Comment: What do you mean with "No collections are not corresponding"? If you did not generate the resource collections then do so.